# How do I determine which version of the RHEL I'm building on?

Tags: rhel, rpm

Under Fedora, I can use this command to get the version:

`rpm -E %{fedora}`

Under CentOS, I can use this command:

`rpm -E %{centos}`

What is the equivalent for Red Hat Enterprise Linux?

Answer (score 2):

I found my own answer. This works on RHEL and on CentOS:

`rpm -E %{rhel}`

Comment: rpm can also tell you the version installed via:

    `rpm -q --qf "%{VERSION}\n" --whatprovides redhat-release`

Answer (score 0):

from man1 `uname` prints the system information as

```
~$ uname -a
Linux host 5.8.9-200.fc32.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Sep 14 18:28:45 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
~$
```

Comment: uname tells you what kernel you are running, and while there is certainly a link between kernel version/release and the version of RHEL, you could have an updated RHEL 7.9 system running a RHEL 7.8 kernel (because 7.9 was just released) and the uname wouldn't reflect what version of RHEL was installed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, didn't know that!

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /etc/redhat-release

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.8 (Maipo)
```